# State remains the same after calling setState, even in the callback of setState

Tags: reactjs, debugging, callback, updates, setstate

I'm facing with weird bug related to `setState`. I know that it is asynchronous, thus I added `console.log(this.state)` in the `callback` function of `setState`, but state remains the same, and no changes are reflected on app. Here is code:

```
  if (response && response.data && response.data.data) {
    if (this._isMounted) {
      const arrangedSenderEmailAddresses = arrangeEmailAddresses(response.data.data);
      console.log('update data: ', arrangedSenderEmailAddresses);
      this.setState({ emailAddresses: arrangedSenderEmailAddresses }, () => {
        console.log('state after update: ', this.state.emailAddresses);
      });
    }
  }
```

`response` is object retrieved from backend.

`console.log('update data: ', arrangedSenderEmailAddresses)` shows new data that should be set on state, but in callback:

`console.log('state after update: ', this.state.emailAddresses);` shows old state.

Did anyone face with such bug?

Answer (score 0):

Even in the callback it will be using the previous value of state, as you are passing in `this.state` to the console log, which doesn't get re-evaluated in that callback, but gets given the old state.

---

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. **Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.**